# AsyncStorage React Native not working

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to keep the user logged in to my app, so I made the following the user log in.

```
AsyncStorage.setItem('@MyStorage:Token', res.data.accessToken)
AsyncStorage.setItem('@MyStorage:Flag', true)
```

And I tried to do so to validate every time I enter the login page

```
componentWillMount() {
    this._validate()
}

_validate = async () => {
    try {
        const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@MyStorage:Flag')
        console.log(value)
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}
```

But none of the `console.log()` is returned, what would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Did you tried to store "true" instead of true?

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(value)`?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you actually call `setItem()` before calling `getItem()`. In particular, [React doesn't support async component lifecycle methods](http://thecodebarbarian.com/async-await-with-react-and-redux-thunk.html), so you should be very careful about using async/await with React.